# Редирект с URL-кодированной ссылки на некодированную

Tags: регулярные-выражения, .htaccess, редирект

Всем доброго дня, нужна помощь по .htaccess

Два дня уже не могу понять как он работает, что только не пробовал.

Перейду к сути, есть ссылка:

```
domain.ru/s_shoping/shop?sid=253%23modal/bundle/82522
```

В ней есть символ `%23`, мне надо заменить на (`#`) hash.
Такие ссылки появляются например если поделится ссылкой в Skype на ios, может и в других программах есть такая же проблема

Как я только не пробовал писать:

```
RewriteRule ^(/shop\?sid=[0-9]*)?%23(modal/bundle/[0-9]*)$ /shop\?sid=$1#modal/bundle/$2 [NE,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)?%23(.*)?$ $1#$2 [NE,R=301,L]
```

В общем перепробовал десяток вариантов, с разными флагами, дополнительными модулями и т.д. но всё бесполезно...
В чем я делаю ошибку? Если используешь одну группу то все работает, если две уже ломается(или если за группой дописать любой символ тоже не срабатывает)
Ничего особенного в этих регулярках нет... Или может тут можно обойтись сменой кодировки...

Заранее благодарю за любую подсказку

Comment: Попробуйте `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*?)%23(.*)$` и сразу после этого `RewriteRule ^/(s_shoping/shop)/?$ /$1?%1#%2 [R,NE,L]`

Answer (score 1):

Если очень нужно сделать редирект, то используйте флаг [`[B]`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b).

> _rewrite has to unescape URLs before mapping them, so backreferences will be unescaped at the time they are applied. Using the B flag,
>   non-alphanumeric characters in backreferences will be escaped.

Символ `%` зарезервирован для обращения к захваченным группам из секции `RewriteCond` внутри секции `RewriteRule`. `mod_rewrite` обрабатывает их иначе, поэтому ваша последовательность `%23` может быть обработана как пустая захвачена группа и заменена на пустую строку. Флаг `[B]` отключает такую обработку.

Чтобы исправить это, добавьте этот флаг в свои правила, например:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)?%23(.*)?$ $1#$2 [NE,R=301,L,B]
```

Проверить работу можно [здесь](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/).

---

На самом деле, это не проблема.
Данные программы кодируют спецсимволы в URL специальным образом.
По факту же последовательность `%23` равнозначна `#` и вам не надо ничего с этим делать.

Раскодируйте значение строки запроса на стороне сервера.
В PHP, например, за это отвечает функция [`urldecode()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.urldecode.php).

Статья на эту тему на Wikipedia: [Кодирование URL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#.D0.9A.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_URL)

> Стандарт URL обладает серьёзным недостатком — в нём можно использовать
>   только ограниченный набор символов US-ASCII, даже меньший, нежели в
>   ASCII: латинские буквы, цифры и лишь несколько знаков пунктуации (- _
>   . ~ +).
>
> Все другие символы необходимо перекодировать, например, такими
>   символами могут быть буквы кириллицы и с диакритическими знаками,
>   лигатуры, иероглифы.
>
> Данная кодировка описана в стандартах RFC 2396 и
>   RFC 3986, и называется англ. URL-encoding, URLencoded или
>   percent‐encoding.
>
> Пример кодирования можно видеть в русскоязычной Википедии,
>   использующей русский язык в URL. Например, строка вида:
>
> ```
> https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Микрокредит
> ```
>
> кодируется как:
>
> ```
> https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82
> ```

---

В ответе использована информация из ответа на вопрос:
[.htaccess url encoded string not passing to page correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13722058/2486051)